# how to implement partial refund in Cybersource Simple Order API

Tags: xml, payment-gateway

Had anyone experience, using cybersource refund. Here is my request, but it only allows full refund.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <requestMessage xmlns="urn:schemas-cybersource-com:transaction-data-1.126">
    <merchantID>brandbank_au_test</merchantID>
    <merchantReferenceCode>437802</merchantReferenceCode>
    <purchaseTotals>
    <currency>AUD</currency>
    <grandTotalAmount>69.12</grandTotalAmount>
   </purchaseTotals>
   <ccAuthReversalService run="false">
    <authRequestID>2J580114GU137032F</authRequestID>
   </ccAuthReversalService>
 </requestMessage>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are able to figure it out, Cybersource has a ccCreditRequest API for partial Refund. Here is an example on how to use it.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <requestMessage xmlns="urn:schemas-cybersource-com:transaction-data-1.126">
      <merchantID>merchantId</merchantID>
      <merchantReferenceCode>437694</merchantReferenceCode>
      <purchaseTotals>
      <currency>AUD</currency>
      <grandTotalAmount>10.0</grandTotalAmount>
      </purchaseTotals>
      <ccCreditService run="true">
          <captureRequestID>4636277164366228701011</captureRequestID>
       </ccCreditService>
     </requestMessage>
```